# Gloabl init params in Wildfly

Tags: tomcat, wildfly

In Tomcat, you could define global init params like this in context.xml:

```
<Context>
  <Parameter name="envName" value="development" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

Is there some equivalent in Wildfly 10?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider defining simple JNDI bindings using naming subsystem:

```
/subsystem=naming/binding=java\:global\/envName:add(binding-type=simple, value=development)
```

And then inject the binding using *@Resource* annotation:

```
@Resource(mappedName ="java:global/envName")
private String envName = null;
```

For more details see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Naming+Subsystem+Configuration